# How to mock middleware in Express to skip authentication for unit test?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon, proxyquire

I have the following in Express

```
 //index.js

 var service = require('./subscription.service');
 var auth = require('../auth/auth.service');
 var router = express.Router();

 router.post('/sync', auth.isAuthenticated, service.synchronise);

 module.exports = router;
```

I want to override or mock isAuthenticated to return this

```
auth.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) { 
  return next(); 
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
it('it should return a 200 response', function(done) {

  //proxyquire here?

  request(app).post('/subscriptions/sync')
  .set('Authorization','Bearer '+ authToken)
  .send({receipt: newSubscriptionReceipt })
  .expect(200,done);
});
```

I have tried mocking index.js using proxyquire - I think I need to stub the router? 
I have also tried to override in the test

```
app.use('/subscriptions', require('./api/subscription'));
```

There must be a simple way to mock this out so I don't need to authenticate the request. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `sinon` to stub `isAuthenticated` method, but you should do that before a reference to `auth.isAuthenticated` is set as a middleware, so before you require the `index.js` and `app` is created. Most likely you would want this in a `beforeEach` hook:

```
var app;
var auth;

beforeEach(function() {
  auth = require('../wherever/auth/auth.service');
  sinon.stub(auth, 'isAuthenticated')
      .callsFake(function(req, res, next) {
          return next();
      });

  // after you can create app:
  app = require('../../wherever/index');
});

afterEach(function() {
  // restore original method
  auth.isAuthenticated.restore();
});

it('it should return a 200 response', function(done) {
  request(app).post('/subscriptions/sync')
  .set('Authorization','Bearer '+ authToken)
  .send({receipt: newSubscriptionReceipt })
  .expect(200,done);
});
```

Please note that even after `auth.isAuthenticated` is restored, existing `app` instance will have stub as a middleware, so you need to create another `app` instance if you need to get an original behavior by some reason.

*Update:* there is a way to alter middleware's behavior without recreating the server each time as explained in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834073/2835868).

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, and it feels like this solution should work for me, but mine is still broken. Any thoughts on this similar problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852873/sinon-stub-being-skipped-as-node-express-middleware

Comment: @LukeSchlangen posted an answer there

Comment: @SergeyLapin Is there any way to mock parameterized middleware using Sinon? middleware definition like as: 

exports.authUser = function (options) { return function (req, res, next) { // Implement the middleware function based on the options object next() } }

Comment: @hareshhanat sure, I believe just the same way, just need to return middleware instead of passing it to callsFake: 

sinon.stub(authModule, 'authUser')
      .callsFake((options) => (req, res, next) => {
          return next();
      });

Comment: @SergeyLapin Yes, got it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I implemented in the next way with Typescript if anyone looking for something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/77440088/3140797